# Creating scrollable list of images

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I thought this would be really simple but its proving to be very difficult. Im trying to create a simple view with a list of 13 images that I can scroll down. Im using the xml code below but the result is not what I expected. I'm getting a scrollable list of images starting with the bottom part of the 5th image and complete images of 6 - 13. at the bottom of the scrollview there is a bunch of empty space about the same size as the space I imagine the missing images would take up..... any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/back"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_gravity="center"           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s1" android:id="@+id/imageView1"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s2" android:id="@+id/imageView2"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s3" android:id="@+id/imageView7"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s4" android:id="@+id/imageView11"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s5" android:id="@+id/imageView10"                
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s6" android:id="@+id/imageView9"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s7" android:id="@+id/imageView8"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s8" android:id="@+id/imageView4"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s9" android:id="@+id/imageView5"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s10" android:id="@+id/imageView6"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s11" android:id="@+id/imageView3"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s12" android:id="@+id/imageView13"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/s13" android:id="@+id/imageView12"    
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using wrap_content for both the imageviews height and width.

Comment: Thanks but already tried that and probably every other combination of fill parent and wrap content :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using a 'GridView' in your case could be a better and most clean solution.